# docker with pycharm 5

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I try to build a docker-based development box for our django app. It's running smoothly.

None of my teammembers will care about that until there is a nice IDE integration, therefore I play the new and shiny [Docker Support in pycharm 5](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/10/announcing-pycharm-5-eap-143-165-docker-integration/).

I followed the linked documentation and pycharm does recognise my web container and it's python interpreter.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
    - .:/srv/app
  links:
    - database
    - search
    - cache
  entrypoint: /home/deployer/web-entrypoint.sh


worker:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/srv/app
  command: celery -A core worker -l info
  links:
    - database
    - search
    - cache

database:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=app_user
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=app_password

data:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql/data

search:
  image: "elasticsearch:1.7"
  command: "elasticsearch --http.bind_host=0.0.0.0"
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"

cache:
  image: "redis:latest"
  ports:
    - "6379"
```

Unfortunately there is no docker-compose support in pycharm, that's why djangos `runserver` failed upon connecting to the database. Therefore I copied the (fortunately predictable) aliases from the web container's `/etc/host`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'app_db',
        'USER': 'app_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'app_password',
        'HOST': 'docker_database_1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://docker_search_1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'app',
    },
}

BROKER_URL = 'redis://docker_cache_1:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
```

Now the database connection error is no longer there, but the output of my django server gives me this:

```
a6993f56e61e:python -u /opt/project/manage.py runserver docker:8001 --traceback
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 08, 2015 - 19:54:29
Django version 1.8.6, using settings 'core.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://docker:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Process finished with exit code 1
```

No stack trace, just this.

What's strange: `python -u /opt/project/manage.py` - what's this? The folder does not exist on both host and the container.

My Django Server conf:

[image: Django server conf]

I tried as well a pure-python conf like this:

[image: Pure Python Implementation]

This is like mega-confusing because it tries again to connect via the "database" link, even if I remove it from the settings at all.

What would be the next steps for debugging?

Bonus question: pyCharm does recognize the installed packages in the project settings, but it can't find it in the code, why?

[image: Failed import from dist-packages]

**UPDATE**

I found out that pyCharm is starting the container for itself and is not using the existing docker container. Hence it looks like pyCharm can only work with a single container, which does not seem to be that useful at all.

Comment: Have updated my answer since I now have a docker-compose environment working very well in pycharm with full debug/test/manage command support. I think you almost have it in your config except don't use the docker-compose shortnames instead use a environment variable to the docker-machine instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that pycharm 5 supports only one container per project. Basically that translates to "Docker support is useless in pyCharm 5".

Multi-container management on top of docker compose is requested here and is awaiting YOUR upvote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137765

Comment: any news on this side? i'm having the same problem and the current support is kind of useless. Who use just one container at a time? it's an app without db basically, strange choice from pycharm

Comment: In my feeling, jetbrains adds to much checkbox features without any values. There are lots of bugs and poorly conceived things that are not getting proper attention in favour of adding the latest hype buzzwords into the release notes.

Comment: Docker support in pycharm is for the python container. It happily leaves my other containers alone (like it should). It does support multiple containers in that I can easily startup multiple runservers etc. Also I can view the logs, inspect, etc on all containers from within pycharm5 itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution. I setup a docker-compose somewhat like yours (postgres, redis, solr). It's set to use a custom DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (called settings.docker) that looks for a DOCKER_IP environment variable to use in the services. All works fine.

Then was trying Pycharm out to get it working with the docker integration since I'm running Windows (hence docker-machine), I can only do a docker-compose run in detached mode. Not very useful for a shell. But the one in Pycharm (as you found out) runs another container and the shell works fine. So you get your django shell even on a windows/mac machine that has to run in detached mode.

Also tests, runserver and any other manage command work fine within PyCharm and debug/breakpoints work.

runserver configuration:
[image: runserver configuration]

interpreter:
[image: interpreter]

In settings.docker we have

```
DOCKER_IP = os.environ.get('DOCKER_IP', '127.0.0.1')
# database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'transaction_hooks.backends.postgis',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'NAME': "dbuser",
        'HOST': DOCKER_IP,
        'POST': 5432,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,
    },
}
# redis
REDIS_URL = "redis://%s:6379/1" % DOCKER_IP
```

You get the idea

Comment: Are you able to connect to the debugger?

Comment: I normally use pydevd remote debugger, even locally (as it's a bit faster). Setup a remove pydevd debug instance and connect to your host post.

Comment: Update on this, it works flawlessly with the debugger. No need for a complicated pydev setup. I'll update my answer above with screenshots and answer any issues.