# Why is PyCharm killing my subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, pycharm

I have a very basic `subprocess.Popen` command like:

```
cmd = ['docker', 'run', '--name=test','server']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I run this in a Python script from terminal, this correctly launches the docker image and the image is persisted until I `docker stop` it.

However, when I run the same code from PyCharm 5, the docker image is immediately stopped when the above line is completed.

I have verified this in the debugger (running `docker ps -a` shows this image immediately dies when launched from PyCharm).

What do I have to do in order to keep my subprocess opened when running with PyCharm? Not being able to run the debugger is quite annoying.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you configure docker to run in PyCharm per this guide: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/. One of the features in PyCharm is that it supports docker. So there is probably something more user friendly per its own configuration you need to follow to get it working?

Comment: @idjaw - Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that blog post about using a Python interpreter that runs in the Docker container as the PyCharm interpreter? It seems like he just needs the subprocess call to execute.

Comment: @BingsF Yes, however, there is a part of the doc that explains how to connect to a docker container. That could be the missing piece.

Comment: There is also this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/10/announcing-pycharm-5-eap-143-165-docker-integration/ . There also seems to be an SO post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33598406/1832539

Comment: It appears from your description that the `docker run' command is executed, but the docker containers dies immediately. Have you checked `docker logs`

Answer (score -2):

Are you printing out the output from the Popen call (stdout and stderr)? What does it say?

Launching subprocesses from an IDE can be tricky, because certain environment variables (like `PATH`) may not be set in the same way as your shell.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.